# For loop alternative to enumerate within data frame

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames (example df below) of various observations that I want to enumerate for each observation in a new data frame.

As the title suggests, I have tried a for loop, but it takes too long per iteration. Example below:

```
flattening <- function(df){
  if(is.null(nrow(df))){
    return(data.frame(temp="foo"))
  } else {
    lengthCheck <- nrow(df)
    dfFlat <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 0,ncol = 0))
    for(i in 1:lengthCheck){
      dfFlat[1,paste0("id",i)] <- df$id[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("date",i)] <- df$date[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("purpose",i)] <- df$purpose[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("type",i)] <- df$type[i]
    }
    return(dfFlat)
  }
}
```

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(553235,165235,235634),
             date=c("2018-01-01","2018-02-25","2019-03-01"),
             purpose=c("A1","B5","D2"),
             type = c("B","TA","FI"))
```

Here is what the result should be:

```
     id1      date1 purpose1 type1    id2      date2 purpose2 type2    id3      date3 purpose3 type3
1 553235 2018-01-01       A1     B 165235 2018-02-25       B5    TA 235634 2019-03-01       D2    FI
```

RESULTS UPDATE:

Here are the microbenchmark results of all user suggestions. Benchmark is based on a list of 10 varying length data frames:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    old 22.39654 23.44767 24.62769 24.05926 24.95069 44.71037   100   b
 andrew 15.46494 16.61251 17.91033 17.26803 18.16550 39.40798   100  a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind converting your `id` variables to strings rather than numbers, you could do something like this...

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(as.vector(t(as.matrix(df)))), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df2) <- outer(names(df),1:nrow(df),paste0)

df2 
     id1      date1 purpose1 type1    id2      date2 purpose2 type2    id3      date3 purpose3 type3
1 553235 2018-01-01       A1     B 165235 2018-02-25       B5    TA 235634 2019-03-01       D2    FI
```

This converts your dataframe to a vector (via a matrix) and sets it as the row of a new dataframe, and then sets the column names using the old column names and the row numbers.

Comment: Not bad. This is 28% faster than my implementation. Let's see if anyone can beat that ;)

Comment: Actually you don't need the `as.matrix` - you can just do `t(df)`.  Might be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

you could use foreach parallel package as follows

```
foreach(i = 1:lengthCheck, .combine = rbind) %dopar%
{
      dfFlat[1,paste0("id",i)] <- df$id[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("date",i)] <- df$date[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("purpose",i)] <- df$purpose[i]
      dfFlat[1,paste0("type",i)] <- df$type[i]
}
```

Comment: To my understanding, using `foreach` does not feed back the results in the same sequence that they are fed in. Would this be accurate to say?